# Issue with WIndows MDHA with visual studio 2013

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I'm trying to learn something about multy hybrid app developing under visual studio 2013 using Apache Cordova. I've just created a new project and i'm trying to build it but when I try to build it for android I get 1 warning and 1 error.

warning:

```
Warning 1   The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets   95  5   helloWorld
```

error:

```
Error   2   The command ""C:\Users\user01\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "Android" --configuration "Debug" --projectDir . --projectName "helloWorld" --language "en-US" --buildServerUrl "" --buildTarget "AndroidEmulator"" exited with code 1.  C:\Users\user01\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets   99  5   helloWorld
```

I've googled those errors but I haven't sorted anything out. Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Does you project have `.ts` files?

Comment: I haven't. are they type script files?

Comment: Yes. This is Typescrpt files. Are by any chance you create new project using Typescrpt MDHA template and then add project with your content?

Comment: no, I haven't. i just made a new cordova project

Comment: There two type of MDHA projects in VS2013. One for Javascript another one for TypeScript. Looks like you are using TypeScript version. But from your question not clear whenether you do any modification to default VS project and what kind of modifications do you made

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of **`Android target (latest version) is not available with Android SDK`**. Make sure the following in your system,

- Go to Android installed folder (for me, C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk)
- Go to tools folder and select "android.bat" Run as Administrator
- Check whether the latest version of Android (ex: API 19) is installed or not
- If it is not installed, select that API, click install by accepting License
- If it is installed, close it and then Go to to root folder(ex: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk)
- Double click on the AVD Manager and create new [AVD](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html)

Now I hope, you can able to build and run the application.